# Python Pyro4 remote object block (like if it was deadlocked)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, deadlock, pyro

I have a problem with Python Pyro4 remote objects which behave as if they were deadlock. Here's how to reproduce the problem (in Windows). Start the name server:

```
set PYRO_HMAC_KEY=some_key
python -m Pyro4.naming
```

Then run the remote object server:

```
import Pyro4
import sys


class Scheduler:
    def test(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    sys.excepthook = Pyro4.util.excepthook

    scheduler = Scheduler()

    Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY='some_key'  

    deamon = Pyro4.Daemon()
    ns = Pyro4.locateNS()
    ns.register("scheduler", deamon.register(scheduler))

    deamon.requestLoop()
```

Then run the client:

```
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process
import Pyro4

class BWModule(Process):

    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.depth = 1


    def run(self): 

        Pyro4.config.HMAC_KEY='some_key'       
        self.scheduler = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:scheduler")                

        print "1"
        sys.stdout.flush()         
        self.scheduler.test()
        print "2"
        sys.stdout.flush()         

        print "depth", self.depth
        sys.stdout.flush() 

        if self.depth < 5:
            for i in range(10):
                newblock = self.duplicate()
                newblock.depth = self.depth + 1
                newblock.start()


    def duplicate(self):
        dup = type(self)()
        return dup



if __name__ == '__main__': 

    sys.excepthook = Pyro4.util.excepthook

    No1 = BWModule()    
    No1.start()
```

When I run this code, I see printed message "depth X" with X from 1 to 3 but no more. I also see at the end of the execution (before nothing else happen) a bunch of 1s without corresponding 2s, which indicates that the call the the Pyro remote object "self.scheduler.test()" has blocked. This makes me think that this is a problem with Pyro rather than with processes (for example, running out of available processes if such a thing is possible). However, if I reduce the process multiplication from 10 to 2 (i.e., replacing "for i in range(10):" by "for i in range(2):" in the client code), the execution goes all the way to depth 5 without blocking...

So here are my questions: What is happining? Why does it block with "for i in range(10):"? Is there a limit of possible "client" processes to a Pyro4 remote object or something like that? Is it a deadlocking problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. For anyone facing a similar problem, this problem seems to be associated with some limit to the number of Pyro proxies that can hold simultaneously a reference on a remote object. Beware however that I'm only conjecturing this. This conclusion is based on the fact that adding

```
del self.scheduler
```

right before

```
if self.depth < 5:
```

in the client code both limits the number of alive proxies and fixes the problem (giving it enough time, the code go up to depth 5 using "for i in range(10):").

EDIT:

As I understand it from [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/config.html) and from some testing, the value of THREADPOOL_MINTHREADS is linked to the maximal number of connections or proxies to a remote object. If I set it to 4, the program freeze (much like if it was deadlock) when the fifth proxy tries to acces my remote object.

There is also some possibly related information [here](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/servercode.html#server-types-and-object-concurrency-model).

Answer (score 0):

Just faced a similar issue, a neater way to do this might be to change

```
 self.scheduler = Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:scheduler")
```

to

```
 with Pyro4.Proxy("PYRONAME:scheduler") as self.scheduler:
    # Rest of code using self.scheduler
 #Rest of code not using self.scheduler
```

This is equivalent to using `del self.scheduler` except you don't need to worry about where you place this - python does the heavy lifting for you.